# Translation of "Take ___ for granted"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I have heard this phrase a lot of times before in forms like:

> Take (anything) for granted.
>
> Don't take (anything) for granted.

I'm not sure about how to translate it:

> Dar (algo) por **terminado/realizado/hecho**

Is this ok? If not, what would be the correct translation of this phrase? Can you give examples of its usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it means: to think that something is true but never have thought about it or wondered why it is true or is this way.

So it can be translated as:

> Dar < algo > por sentado
>
> Dar < algo > por hecho

Comment: In English at least, "to take for granted" describes something you have but are not necessarily thankful or grateful for (for example, your family or easy access to medical care or freedom of speech). It often comes up when situations change so something is no longer available and you realize, "Wow, I really took ... for granted."

Comment: Also, what's the difference between *Dar algo por sentado* and *Darlo algo por sentado*?

Comment: @jrdioko "darlo algo por sentado" is incorrect because "lo" it's a subtitute for algo so "Dar algo por sentado" = "Darlo por sentado"

Comment: @Laura of course. I wanted to express that it was used with "something" but forgot to remove "lo". Thanks.

Comment: @jrdioko these expressions also match the definition you give. Indeed it seems that the expression in English has those 2 meanings as well as it's stated here: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/granted

Answer (score 3):

Another possible (and usual) translation is:

```
dar <algo> por descontado
```

Answer (score 2):

`To take something for granted` translates literally to `dar algo por sentado`, and both expressions mean exactly the same.

`To take it for granted` can be a little bit shorter in its Spanish version since the object can be included in the verb *dar*, as in `darlo por sentado.`